# In ros2_control,the foxy version, how can the ros2_control_node read the hardware_interface and controller info?

Tags: c++, ros2

here is the [source code](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/blob/foxy/controller_manager/src/ros2_control_node.cpp) of ros2_control_node:

```
 int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

  std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Executor> executor =
    std::make_shared<rclcpp::executors::MultiThreadedExecutor>();
  std::string manager_node_name = "controller_manager";

  auto cm = std::make_shared<controller_manager::ControllerManager>(executor, manager_node_name);

  // TODO(anyone): Due to issues with the MutliThreadedExecutor, this control loop does not rely on
  // the executor (see issue #260).
  // When the MutliThreadedExecutor issues are fixed (ros2/rclcpp#1168), this loop should be
  // converted back to a timer.
  std::thread cm_thread([cm]() {
    // load controller_manager update time parameter
    int update_rate = DEFAULT_UPDATE_RATE;
    if (!cm->get_parameter("update_rate", update_rate))
    {
      RCLCPP_WARN(cm->get_logger(), "'update_rate' parameter not set, using default value.");
    }
    RCLCPP_INFO(cm->get_logger(), "update rate is %d Hz", update_rate);

    rclcpp::Time end_period = cm->now();

    // Use nanoseconds to avoid chrono's rounding
    rclcpp::Duration period(std::chrono::nanoseconds(1000000000 / update_rate));

    while (rclcpp::ok())
    {
      // wait until we hit the end of the period
      end_period += period;
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds((end_period - cm->now()).nanoseconds()));

      // execute "real-time" update loop
      cm->read();
      cm->update();
      cm->write();
    }
  });

  executor->add_node(cm);
  executor->spin();
  cm_thread.join();
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

and the demo run it by [launch.py](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/blob/foxy/ros2_control_demo_bringup/launch/rrbot_system_position_only.launch.py) file in a methods of:

```
    controller_manager_node = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="ros2_control_node",
        parameters=[robot_description, rrbot_controllers],
        output={
            "stdout": "screen",
            "stderr": "screen",
        },
    )
```

where the `robot_description` and `rrbot_controllers` is

```
    robot_description_content = Command(
        [
            PathJoinSubstitution([FindExecutable(name="xacro")]),
            " ",
            PathJoinSubstitution(
                [
                    FindPackageShare("rrbot_description"),
                    "urdf",
                    "rrbot_system_position_only.urdf.xacro",
                ]
            ),
            " prefix:=",
            LaunchConfiguration("prefix"),
            " use_fake_hardware:=",
            LaunchConfiguration("use_fake_hardware"),
            " fake_sensor_commands:=",
            LaunchConfiguration("fake_sensor_commands"),
            " slowdown:=",
            LaunchConfiguration("slowdown"),
        ]
    )

    robot_description = {"robot_description": robot_description_content}

    rrbot_controllers = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [
            FindPackageShare("ros2_control_demo_bringup"),
            "config",
            "rrbot_controllers.yaml",
        ]
    )
```

I am a beginner of ros2 control and C++ program.I am not very understand of how this ros2_control_node read the description and controllers information. And how does the ros2_control_node know `the read()` and `write()` that write in the hardware_interface?